# Wicket 8 web.xml myproject example

Tags: apache, wicket, web.xml

Never having use Wicket before I installed Apache Wicket 8.0.0-M8 on Windows 10. I also installed apache-tomcat-9.0.7.

I replaced the following Tomcat conf folder files with those provided by wicket:

context.xml, server.xml

I used Eclipse Neon's Maven option to create a project called myproject. Eclipse generated the following web.xml file which I relocated to:

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps\myproject\WEB-INF

That web.xml file looks like this:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
  <display-name>myproject</display-name>
  <!--
    There are three means to configure Wickets configuration mode and they 
    are tested in the order given.

    1) A system property: -Dwicket.configuration 
    2) servlet specific <init-param> 
    3) context specific <context-param>

    The value might be either "development" (reloading when templates change) or 
    "deployment". If no configuration is found, "development" is the default. -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>wicket.myproject</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
      <param-value>com.quantech.myproject.WicketApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicket.myproject</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Eclipse found the following problems with this file:

- Referenced file contains errors (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd).  web.xml /myproject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF  line 1  XML Problem

TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee'.

When I load web.xml into XMLSpy I get the message:

This file is not valid. Root element 'web-app' is not defined in DTD/Schema.

Anyone have a clue what is wrong here?

thanks,

Terry

Answer (score 1):

```
 I replaced the following Tomcat conf folder files with those provided by wicket:

      context.xml, server.xml
```

Wicket doesn't provide such files!

```
 Eclipse generated the following web.xml file

 Eclipse found the following problems with this file:
```

Bad Eclipse!
Just ignore these errors/warnings. Tomcat won't complain.
To make Eclipse happy you will have tweak its configuration.  I can't help you with that though. I use different IDE.